# Using Sparkle or an alternative for a sandboxed macOS app

Tags: macos, sandbox, sparkle

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am working on a sandboxed macOS application, and I need to implement a self-updating feature for it. I have considered using the Sparkle framework, but I am concerned about potential issues related to the sandboxing restrictions.

Can anyone share their experience with using Sparkle in a sandboxed macOS application or recommend an alternative solution for implementing a self-updating system that adheres to the sandboxing requirements? I'd appreciate any suggestions or best practices in implementing this feature.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You should link to the research you did, what you tried (including relevant code snippets) and the error message sir issues you’re running into.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Sparkle version 2, as this fully supports a sandboxed application.
Follow the [instructions](https://sparkle-project.org/documentation/) on the Sparkle web site.